# Use Python to move files based on part of their names and a list of specifications

Tags: python

I have a folder with over 4k recordings that I need to sort based on three substrings that are present in the file names.

First, I need to select the files based on the Rec number, after that based on the date of recording and finally based on the test (verSacc, antisaccades, etc).

Examples of the file naming below:
EVALAB_Stimuli_26 feb 2017_antisaccades_Rec 01.tsv; EVALAB_Stimuli_15 ian 2018_antisaccades_Rec 02.tsv; EVALAB_Stimuli_11iulie2018_verSacc_DC011V1.tsv; EVALAB_Stimuli_11iulie2018_verSacc_DC026V2.tsv

I decided to start the sorting based on the Recording number. I made a script that extracted the specific column from Excel to a Python list. So far so good – I have generated the list with over 300 unique items.

After that, the main script will iterate the files in the path folder and copy the files that have recs in their name to the new_path.

Well, if print the file names, at the end, all seems good. But the shutil seems not to work – either in copies 6-7 files and stops or the error comes instantly. 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Cluj-EVALAB_Stimuli_10_noi_2017_antisaccades_DC079V1.tsv'

I have tested this script on a folder with 50 recordings and it runs without errors. Any ideas?

Also, I am aiming to do this more rudimentary, in three steps – first sort on the recording, second sort the remain based on date and third based on test. Do you see any flaws in this, beside of not being elegant?

Many thanks in advance!

```
import os
import shutil
path = 'E:\\ET'
new_path = 'E:\\ET\\New'
files = os.listdir(path)
recs = ['DC001V2', 'DC002V1', 'DC003V1', 'Rec_01', 'Rec_02', 'Rec_03'] #the list has more than 300 items, many in the format above but a few dozen with peculiar names like anxiety, borderline, etc.
for file in files:
    for rec in recs:
        if rec in file:
            print(file) #printing goes just fine
            shutil.copy(file, new_path)
```

Comment: You probably need to join the path and the filename to get the full path to the file - `shutil.copy(os.path.join(path, file), new_path)`

Comment: Works like a charm! 500 files and counting copied :) Many thanks!

Comment: Any idea of how could I run this piece of code in all the subfolders of a directory? There are about 8 folders with 3 subfolders each. Thank you very much!